Do third party employment agencies prefer you to be an hourly employee or salaried employee?
I've been given two employment options with a third party employment agency, hourly versus salaried.
In the hourly option, I pay for health insurance entirely myself.
In the salaried option, I get two weeks of vacation, five personal days, and the usual 11 national holidays, which are all paid for, of course.
If I were to subtract the two weeks of vacation, five personal days, 11 national holidays, and the cost of the best option health insurance, and assume that I work 40 hours a week, the hourly option comes out to be about four percent higher in annual earnings.
Is there anything about the salaried option that accounts for the four percent difference?

Why does it matter. Tgey are never going to he identical. Things have probably been rounded. Accept the one you want.

You haven't given a country, but my first thoughts would be to wonder about any statutory rights or benefits you haven't enumerated.
If nothing like that applies it could just be that the hourly option is giving you a small premium to compensate for assuming the risks that come from being hourly and without benefits vs having a stable income and them.

The game is rigged. Not really in a bad way, but you are given a choice. It is reasonable to start out with the logic that for steady work that both options will come out the same. Sharpen up your pencil and check your numbers.
Why would they? Because the temp agency needs reliable staff and they need to be considered as reliable by their clients.
There is no value to them in paying out different amounts for the same labor with the same benefits long-term.
Any differences will come out to who pays for something. If you can buy it for less, then take that option (which ever one gives you the most cash). If they pay less for it (health care for example), take that option.
That means you will have to do a great deal of comparison shopping to make your decision.
It is unlikely that you will work a significant amount of overtime if you go hourly. But, if you think or know that it is possible, that should affect your decision. The reason that I say that it is unlikely that you will work overtime, is why would they offer hourly if they can offer salary? That only adds uncertainty to the model.
As others have pointed out, contractor is different than hourly, so that is something to confirm since it changes everything that is being discussed.

Hourly has the advantage that any overtime is paid. Salaried employee are often expected to work "until its done". Salaried has typically more flexibility in work hours but often ends up more than 40 hours a week.

In the hourly option, I pay for health insurance entirely myself.

That would be unusual. Are you sure this is really "hourly" and not a "contractor"?
Other than health insurance, you really should look at other benefits. In the US that would include Social Security, 401k or IRA, Medicare, disability (long & short) etc. Other countries have similar constructs.
Contractors have to pay all of those out of their pockets and that's what they typically charge 2-3 times the effective hourly rate of a salaried employee. Rate of hourly workers is much lower than that for a contractor but typically hourly employees get a full set of benefits.

Hourly does not exactly guarantee that overtime is paid.  As an hourly, when I put down that I worked 8.25 hours in a day, the director reached out to me and told me that I needed to change that because the company would not pay for more than 8 hours a day or 40 hours a week.  The return on that is that if I need to take time off, I don't have to wait for PTO to accrue, I just bank unpaid hours worked and use those as needed.
